# Indexing problem in a for loop? Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 27630). MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing, matlab-figure

I have a code to process my acoustic data (altimeter soundings to monitor seagrass heights in shallow water). The data comes in separate files for each survey section and so I have a total of 6 different sized .txt docs. I have loaded everything in but when I try to average in a loop every 7 pings I am getting and error.

```
Index in position 2 exceeds array bounds (must not exceed 27630)   Error in VA500readv2 (line 55)
            tmp_depth = ping_depth(:,i-x:i+x); % find all depth values for x pings before and after ping i.
```

This is what the section of code looks like, any help is much appreciated. I will also copy the variable sizes in. Thank you for help in advance.
Also I have already ran the full script on two previous data files and it worked absolutely fine so I am unsure what's gone wrong when trying to run the the third. Thanks again.

I am trying to index two columns(time and pings) but I am not sure how to do this the best way :// Below is half of my code and the loops that I have been using, the bit at the start (for loop and k_ind) creates a matrix the size of 28022 when I need 27630 and I am unsure how to fix this.

```
% index the VA500 pings
k = regexp(C{2},'sig');
k_ind = [];
for i = 1:length(k)
    if cell2mat(k(i)) == 1
        k_ind = [k_ind; i];
    end
end
ping_id = k_ind+1;

% find time of each ping
ping_time = time(ping_id);

% Find number of rows in ping, and create record of depth and correlation
% value (proxy for acoustic intensity)
data = char(C{2});
ping_corr = [];
ping_depth = [];
for i = 1:length(ping_id)-1
    tmp = ping_id(i+1)-ping_id(i);
    try
        for j = 1:tmp
            ping_depth(j,i) = str2num(data(ping_id(i)+j,1:5)); % depth
            ping_corr(j,i) = str2num(data(ping_id(i)+j,7:end)); % correlation value (acoustic intensity)
        end
    end
end
  
ping_num = 1:1:length(ping_corr);
%% Create ping average dataset (moving window). 
% Make each ping record an average signal from the surrounding x number of pings (if x is 2 then average is 5 ping moving window). 
x = 3;
bin_depth = 0:0.05:8; % depths bins in which to average (change the middle value to change resolution (set currently at 0.05m with max depth 10m)
bin_corr = zeros(length(bin_depth),length(ping_id-(x*2))); % create blank matrix
count = 1;
for i = x+1:length(bin_corr(1,:))-(x+2)
    tmp_depth = ping_depth(:,i-x:i+x); % find all depth values for x pings before and after ping i
    tmp_depth = tmp_depth(:);
    tmp_corr = ping_corr(:,i-x:i+x); % find all depth values for x pings before and after ping i
    tmp_corr = tmp_corr(:);
    tmp_bins = discretize(tmp_depth,bin_depth); % allocate data to depth bins
    for ii = 1:length(bin_depth)
        bin_corr(ii, count) = nanmean(tmp_corr(tmp_bins == ii)); % calc bin average values for each ping window
        if isnan(bin_corr(ii, count)) == 1
            bin_corr(ii, count) = 0;
        end  
    end
    count = count+1;
end
```

k_ind    28022x1 double,
ping_corr  48x27630 double,
ping_depth  48x27630 double,
ping_id  28022x1 double,
k  390908x1 cell,
ping_num   1x27630 double,
ping_time  28022x1 double,
time 390908x1 double ,
tmp_bins  336x1 double,
tmp_corr  336x1 double,
tmp_depth  336x1 double,
data  390908x37 char,
bin_depth  1x161 double,
bin_corr  161x28022 double.

I have no idea how to fix this and preallocate for an array the same size as the pings because for some reason its made a different size. Thank you for your help in advance, its much appreciated.

Comment: if two files already ran fine, maybe something is wrong with the third file, and not your script?

Comment: It was actually the version of MATLAB that i was using screwing me up it ran fine with the 2021 version just not the 2020 one and worked fine in the end, completely threw me off aha thank you!